# scipy pdist() on a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, pdist

I have a large dataframe (e.g. 15k objects), where each row is an object and the columns are the numeric object features. It is in the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [0, 0, 1],
                    'B' : [2, 3, 4],
                    'C' : [5, 0, 1],
                    'D' : [1, 1, 0]},
                    columns= ['A','B', 'C', 'D'], index=['first', 'second', 'third'])
```

I want to calculate the pairwise distances of all objects (rows) and read that [scipy's pdist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) function is a good solution due to its computational efficiency. I can simply call:

```
res = pdist(df, 'cityblock')
res
>> array([ 6.,  8.,  4.])
```

And see that the `res` array contains the distances in the following order: `[first-second, first-third, second-third]`.

My question is how can I get this in a matrix, dataframe or (less desirably) dict format so I know exactly which pair each distance value belongs to, like below:

```
       first second third
first    0      -     -
second   6      0     -
third    8      4     0
```

Eventually, I think having the [distance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix) as a pandas DataFrame may be convenient, since I may apply some ranking and ordering operations per row (e.g. find the top N closest objects to object `first`).

Answer (score 21):

Oh, I found the answer on this [webpage](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@s@c@ScipyNumpy_book_examples-HEAD@python_examples@scipy_352_ex1.py/33/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist). Apparently, there is a dedicated function for that named [squareform()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html). Not deleting my question for the time being in case it may be helpful for someone else.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
res = pdist(df, 'cityblock')
squareform(res)
pd.DataFrame(squareform(res), index=df.index, columns= df.index)
>>        first  second  third
>>first       0       6      8
>>second      6       0      4
>>third       8       4      0
```